# Under High load XDocument.Parse Creating errors

Tags: c#, xml, rest, streamreader, linq-to-xml

I am trying to access this webservice, The problem is that sometimes XDocument.Parse is not able to process and generates an error System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.  on the line:

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);

Even though the XML sent is correct according to my logs.

I was wondering, Is it possible that the StreamReader is not working properly

```
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
    {
        xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);
```

By the way this is all under a Custom HttpHandler.

Can someone please me guide in the right direction for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does it work any more consistently if you use

```
XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
```

instead of XDocument.Parse?

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample doesn't include logging of the read inputstream. The problem is prior to this point.